# Обращение к div, которое подходит условию If/else

Tags: javascript, jquery

В своем коде я проверяю `div` на наличие высоты больше `50px`. Я хочу добавлять к нему класс и элемент(видно в коде), если он выше и использую для этого `this`.

Вот сам код:

```
if ($('.reviewer-text').height() > 50) {
    $(this).addClass('fullHidden');
    $(this).after('<div class="reviewer-text-open">Читать дальше</div>');
}
```

Консоль выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Как я понимаю, в `this` не попадают элементы, которые подходят условиям и он попросту пустой. Возможно `this` не применим к `if/else`? Буду рад любой помощи!

UPD:

Нашел решение:

```
$(".reviewer-text").each(function(){
    var _self = $(this);

    if (_self.height() > 50){
        _self.addClass('fullHidden');
        _self.after('<div class="reviewer-text-open">Читать дальше</div>');
}
});
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140698/if-elements-height-is-greater-than-x-addclass-portrait-else-addclass-landscap)

Comment: Где в представленном коде `createDocumentFragment`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский after вызывает его, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Расположите пожалуйста в вопрос весь свой код (html и js), чтобы можно было разобраться

Comment: `Возможно this не применим к if/else` --- если он не в каком-либо методе jquery 
 или его колбэке, то да, не применим. Надо посмотреть контекст применения

Comment: Код выложить не могу) 
Но да, это весь код, без методов выше
Хотелось бы понять, как можно было бы завернуть этот код так, чтобы в this попадали именно те блоки, которые отвечают условиям

Comment: Но код находится в каком-то методе или функции, которая срабатывает по какому-либо событию? Или нет? Не ясно. Или это при полной загрузке документа работает? Опять же это какой-то метод.. `$(this)` - по задумке должен указывать на `$('.reviewer-text')` ? Не хватает данных и контекста

Comment: По задумке - да. Грубо говоря добавить класс `fullHidden` ко всем  `.reviewer-text`, которые выше `50px`.
Код не находится ни в чем, простая проверка

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка не в этом коде, он не может определить переменную/метод  'createDocumentFragment', посмотри может он где-то используется у тебя во всём коде.

Comment: Та вроде нет, вот весь код который затрагивает участок html, с которым я сейчас работаю

`if ($('.reviewer-text').height() > 50) {
    $(this).addClass('fullHidden');
    $(this).after('<div class="reviewer-text-open">Читать дальше</div>');
}
$('.reviewer-text-open').click(function(){
 $(this).siblings('.reviewer-text').removeClass('fullHidden');
 $(this).addClass('hiddenButton');
});`

Comment: В ошибке из консоли так же упоминается сам jquery файл

at xe (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Pe (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.after (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at main.js:167

Comment: если ты работаешь в vs code, то там есть лупа, слева под всеми файлами, можешь туда вбить "createDocumentFragment" и посмотреть где он используется

Comment: Работаю в sublime, попробую поставить vs и затестить, спасибо